# Unable to find anchor tag for href link on goolge search page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
# Input data file
    df = pd.read_csv('BookSD.csv', usecols=[0], encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
    df.columns = ['model_name']

# Output file
    csv_file = open('sundown_scrape.csv', 'w')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    df_result = pd.DataFram`your text`e(columns=['Model_name', 'Features', 'Specification'])

    headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like    Gecko)       Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"}

    links = []
    model_list = ['SALT-200.4', 'SALT-2000.6'] 

    def get_google_search_links_sundown(query_model):
        href_pattern = re.compile(r'.*https://www.sundownaudio.com.*')
        for query in query_model:
            url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query}"
            #print(url)
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            #response.raise_for_status()
            #print(response)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')
            #Find relevant HTML elements to extract data
            search_results = soup.find('a', href=href_pattern) ###### THIS LINE SEEMS TO BE A PROBLEM
        
            #for result in search_results:
            #   link = result.find("a")
            # If url (Search result) is received then extract the href link
            if search_results:
                href = search_results.get("href")
                if href.startswith("/url?q=https://www.sundownaudio.com/index.php/"):
                    href = href[7:]  # Removing the "/url?q=" part from the link
                    if "&sa" in href:  # Removing any additional parameters in the link
                        href = href.split("&sa")[0]
                    links.append(href)
            else:
                print ('No sundown link found in this a-tag')
        return links  # Need to pass list for all model in function

# Fetching search result for desired model query
    links_fn = get_google_search_links_sundown(model_list)

    str_links = ""
    print("Links found:")
    for link in links_fn:
        str_links += link
        print(str_links)
```

I am totally confused why my script is pulling a `href` link for SALT-200.4 but it does not work for "SALT-2000.6".

I have tried the script to pass each individually and still getting the same results. I have tried different parser types, header in get requests without improvements. Href links for both should be fetched as the HTML result is showing same on  chrome inspection for `url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query}"`

Note that I am not able to search by div-class due to dynamic nature of google search results

Please suggest what am I doing wrong here. I would like to solve this problem using Beautifulsoup for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `q=SALT-2000.6` search does not contain a result with `https://www.sundownaudio.com`, just `https://sundownaudio.com` (note that the `www` is missing), so you need to account for that in your pattern.

[image: ss]

Maybe just search for `sundownaudio.com`?

Comment: OMG, i just cannot believe I spent  hours for this stupid mistake and all this time I thought my code is wrong. I just picked up on python after like a year so I doubt myself !

Thanks a lot !
Btw, I am trying to gauge my scripting skills so if you do not mind how do you see this script

Comment: @Cryptic happy to help! I can't really comment on your code structure since my own isn't very clean, but it works, and is not too hard to debug, so that has to be some kind of good (right?); on a very small and rather pedantic note: you don't need to check *`if "&sa" in href:`* before `href = href.split("&sa")[0]` since `.split` will return an array of length 1 even if the parameter isn't there in the main string